# Create a Counter in a ranking table

Tags: php, counter

I have a table of articles that are arranged by the number of visits, where the most visited one is on top, i.e it has Rank of 1. I tried adding a Rank column in the table, but can't get it to work. The Rank column does not exist in the Database, so this should be an incremental counter that starts with 1 and ends with the number of articles listed in the table.
Here's my code, which does not work

```
  <table class="resultsTable" width="100%">
   <tr>
     <th style="width:10%">Rank</th>
     <th style="width:50%">Post Title</th>
     <th style="width:20%">Post Type</th>
     <th style="width:20%">Hits</th>
   </tr>


   <?php foreach($popular_articles as $article) { 
            //create array for most popular
          ?>
//set counter variable
$counter = 1; 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

   <tr>
      echo "<td style="width:10%">".$counter."</td>";
     <td style="width:50%"><?php echo $article->art_title; ?></td>
     <td style="width:20%"><?php echo $article->art_type; ?></td>
     <td style="width:20%"><?php if($article->art_hit_count){ echo '<b>'.$article->art_hit_count.'</b>'; }else { echo '<b>0</b>'; } ?> times.</td>
   </tr>
     $counter++; //increment counter by 1 on every pass 
 echo  <?php } ?>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the counter must be done in PHP. Currently the line that does that is in the HTML:

```
$counter++; //increment counter by 1 on every pass
```

I also removed the `while`, since it didn't seem to do anything, as if it was accidentally pasted there.
The loop should look like this:

```
<?php 
  foreach($popular_articles as $article) { 

  //set counter variable
  $counter = 1; 

   <tr>
     <td style="width:10%"><?php echo $counter; ?></td>";
     <td style="width:50%"><?php echo $article->art_title; ?></td>
     <td style="width:20%"><?php echo $article->art_type; ?></td>
     <td style="width:20%"><?php 
  if($article->art_hit_count){ 
    echo '<b>'.$article->art_hit_count.'</b>'; 
  }else { 
    echo '<b>0</b>'; 
  } ?> times.</td>
   </tr>
<?php
   $counter++; //increment counter by 1 on every pass 
} ?>
```

Alternatively, you can display the counter and update it in one go:

```
<td style="width:10%"><?php echo $counter++; ?></td>";

     ...

<?php
   // $counter++; // You won't be needing this anymore.
} ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to initialize your counter before the loop (in the commentaries, I can see a $counter = 1, but it's trully executed.

And at the end, you try to increment a variable but you're not in a PHP script, so it can not work. Try my corrected version to see if it work.

```
<table class="resultsTable" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:10%">Rank</th>
        <th style="width:50%">Post Title</th>
        <th style="width:20%">Post Type</th>
        <th style="width:20%">Hits</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $counter = 1;
        foreach($popular_articles as $article) { 
        //create array for most popular 
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td style="width:10%"> <?php echo $counter; ?></td>;
        <td style="width:50%"> <?php echo $article->art_title; ?></td>
        <td style="width:20%"> <?php echo $article->art_type; ?></td>
        <td style="width:20%"> 
            <?php if($article->art_hit_count){ 
                    echo '<b>'.$article->art_hit_count.'</b>'; 
                } else { 
                    echo '<b>0</b>'; 
                } ?> times. </td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        $counter++; //increment counter by 1 on every pass 
        } //the end of FOR loop ?>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to make a link for the art_title. Just replace this line :

```
<td style="width:50%"> <?php echo $article->art_title; ?></td>
```

By this one :

```
<td style="width:50%"><a href="your-link.com/page-you-wanna-show.php"> <?php echo $article->art_title; ?></a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great. There was a dangling ; in the counter column but it didnt interfere in the proper counting. I wonder, can I make the art_title to be a clickable link, and how that syntax would work?

Comment: I eddited my answer so you can make a clickable link. As you can see, I just added a <a href=""> </a> balise surrounding the PhP code that will print the art-title.
You still have to find a working link to redirect to. Please don't hesitate to validate my answer if you think it's appropriate.